# Combining three fields as date - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Say I have three fields, `date`,`time`,`ETA`, how would I combine them all into 1 output - `resultDate`?

`Date`(date type) is 2016-02-02

`Time` (time type) is 23:45:00

`ETA` (int type) is 19 minutes

so, the result would ideally be: `2016-02-03 00:04:00`

Comment: What are the data types of the inputs? Are you looking for a formatted string in output or a date time?

Comment: I've updated the question with the types. And regarding the output, I guess a dateTime would be best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select timestamp('2016-02-02', '23:45:00') + interval 19 minute
```

returns '2016-02-03 00:04:00'

So in your case you can use

```
timestamp(Date, Time) + interval ETA minute
```